# javascript triggering virus scan

Tags: javascript, virus-scanning

We have observation for a javascript method which taking more time than anticipated, realised that a VirusScan is kicked everytime that javascript method called which is using innerHTML code. We have not yet concluded.

But just want to know if any of the members faced anything similar ? (VirusScan kicked automatically when parts of javascript being executed like innerHTML or addfragement etc)

Thanks.

Comment: Which kind of anti virus software are you using?

Comment: mcafee is our virus software.